# How to scrape a table using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

What I want is to scrape a table, and save the data in an Array like `result=[tr][ts]`.

How can I make the result I want?

I'm trying something like this:

```
const row = await mainframe.$$eval('#clasificacion > .panel > .table- responsive > #resultadosTable > tbody > tr ', trs => trs.map((tr) =>{
console.log(tr);
return tr.textContent;}));
```

But the result is like `result=[tr]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following method to obtain a 2D array of table cell `textContent` which can be accessed via `row[rowNum][cellNum]`:

```
const selector = '#clasificacion > .panel > .table-responsive > #resultadosTable > tbody > tr';

const row = await mainframe.$$eval(selector, trs => trs.map(tr => {
    const tds = [...tr.getElementsByTagName('td')];
    return tds.map(td => td.textContent);
}));

// console.log(row[rowNum][cellNum]); <-- textContent
```